# A question on Grothendieck's paper On the de Rham cohomology of algebraic varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

In the paper,

http://www.numdam.org/article/PMIHES_1966__29__95_0.pdf

Grothendieck proves the isomorphism between algebraic de Rham cohomology and Betti cohomology, i.e. for a smooth quasi-projective variety $X$ over $\mathbb{C}$, we have
\begin{equation}
H^i_{\text{dR}}(X/\mathbb{C}) \simeq H^i(X^{\text{an}},\mathbb{C})
\end{equation}
The algebraic de Rham cohomology $H^i_{\text{dR}}(X/\mathbb{C})$ is the hypercohomology of the complex $\Omega^*_{X}$ of algebraic forms, while $H^i(X^{\text{an}},\mathbb{C})$ could also be computed as the hypercohomology of the holomorphic forms $\Omega^{h,*}_{X^{an}}$. Naively, it seems straightforward that a direct application of Serre's GAGA to the two complexes of forms would imply this isomorphism, but I remember someone mentions that this naive argument does not work, but why? References are sincerely appreciated!

Comment: Good question ! From this mathoverflow thread (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17937/algebraic-de-rham-cohomology-vs-analytic-de-rham-cohomology) it seems that it *does* follow from GAGA at least in the projective smooth case, but we need some special care when comparing the spectral sequences since the differentials are not maps of $\mathcal{O}$-modules.